# Order isomorphism between $(-\infty,0)$ to $(0, \infty)$

Tags: order-theory

Is there an explicit order isomorphic function between $(-\infty,0)$ to $(0, \infty)$?
There should be one, because both are order isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Map $x$ to $-1/x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

Suppose $a, b \in (-\infty, 0)$ with $a < b$ in the usual sense. Define $f : (-\infty, 0) \to (0, \infty)$ by

$$f(x) = \tan\left(\arctan(x)+{\pi\over 2}\right)$$

and in fact$^{(*)}$ $$f(x) = -{1\over x}$$

Then

$$a < b \Longleftrightarrow f(a) < f(b)$$

---

(*) Kudos to Henning for pointing this out, see below.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\tan(\arctan(x)+\pi/2))$ equals $-\dfrac{1}{x}$...

Comment: Yes, quite right. Which lands us with David Mitra's answer. I still like the idea though of swapping "infinite" for "finite":

$$(-\infty,0) \to (-\pi/2,0) \to (0,\pi/2) \to (0,\infty)$$